# Multi branch pipeline with bitbucket build status notifier plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, bcbsn

I have a multi branch pipeline job in my jenkins server and I tried to notify the build status using bitbucket cloud build status notifier plugin.

I configured the settings provided in [notifier](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Cloud+Build+Status+Notifier+Plugin) plugin and added the notifier script function in the beginning and end of my Jenkinsfile.

**Jenkinsfile:**

```
node {
    stage 'Build'
        bitbucketStatusNotify ( buildState: 'INPROGRESS' )
        .......
        .......
        bitbucketStatusNotify ( buildState: 'SUCESS' )
}
```

When I run the jenkins build it trigger the notifier script and return done statement in the console.

```
Entering stage Build
Proceeding
[Pipeline] bitbucketStatusNotify
Sending build status INPROGRESS for commit 84bf788cc9ccc8c31df5719da383cab003c97582 to BitBucket is done!
[Pipeline] bat
[master] Running batch script
```

But the notifier icon is not visible or set in the bitbucket cloud.

[image]

Is there anything I missed to configure?

Answer (score 3):

documentation/releasenotes at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Cloud+Build+Status+Notifier+Plugin

says 
Using Jenkins 2 pipeline
Add the following at the beginning of your Jenkinsfile:

```
bitbucketStatusNotify ( buildState: 'INPROGRESS' )
```

And add the following at the ending of your Jenkinsfile:

```
bitbucketStatusNotify ( buildState: 'SUCCESSFUL' )
```

the readme on github is more complete: https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-build-status-notifier-plugin