# Is there a Jenkins pipeline equivalent of "Only show latest build status"?

Tags: build, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, bcbsn

We're in the process of migrating to Jenkins pipeline. We use Jenkins to update the build status of our branches/PRs in Bitbucket.

One of our merge checks in Bitbucket is "Check the last commit for at least 1 successful build and no failed builds". This means that we can't merge unless there is 1 successful build of the latest commit on Jenkins, and no failed builds of the latest commit.

Sometimes, Jenkins builds fail for reasons unrelated to the code and the build is fine next time you run it. However, this means that the branch can't be merged as there has been at least one failed build.

To get around this, we were previously able to tick the box in the build status notifier plugin configuration that said "Only show latest build status". As of yet, we're unable to find any equivalent way to configure this in a Jenkinsfile. Does anyone know if it's possible, and if so how?

This question is a duplicate of [Multi branch pipeline with bitbucket build status notifier plugin in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39226643/multi-branch-pipeline-with-bitbucket-build-status-notifier-plugin-in-jenkins), but that question was never really answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your use case it's covered by the [Build REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/6.10.0/bitbucket-build-rest.html) of Bitbucket, and there is even a step-by-step example of your exact case, being [last build failed for external reasons, and a new build succeeds](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/updating-build-status-for-commits/)

In order to overwrite the status of an already reported build, you will need to use the same `commit sha` and the same `key`

Regarding the [Bitbucket Build Status Notifier](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket-build-status-notifier/), it allows you to specify a `buildKey` as an optional parameter. You should make sure to specify this parameter, and that the parameter is always the same for all builds of the same job.

That way, a new build of the same last-commit will overwrite the last one, as it will be using the same sha and the same key.

See the API section of the plugin documentation for additional parameters.